# Logout from Apple-Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-sign-in

How does one actually logout from Apple SignIn after subscribing to this `getCredentialState` method from `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider` object (after this step) [How to Sign Out of Apple After Being Authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836179/how-to-sign-out-of-apple-after-being-authenticated).

Basically I'm asking where should I go and revoked access so that this method here can be invoked within the App.

Comment: Ah, it is because you accidently used Apple-Sign-Out, instead of Apple-Sign In, common mistake.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this from the iOS Settings. Open up the Setting app in your iPhone and tap on your name at the top. Then press `Password & Security`, then `Apple ID login` They listed all the apps there and you can delete any of them to revoke access.

Comment: Is there a way to do it programatically through your own app however?

Comment: @Return-1 have you found a solution for that?

Comment: any solution for that now? @Return-1

Comment: did anyone manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: no... there is no solution