# Sign in with Apple in React Native returning null

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-sign-in

I'm having a problem with Sign in with Apple in React Native. At first it is returning email and name with value but in second attempt it is now returning null.

1st attempt:

```
"email": c@gmail.com, "fullName": {"familyName": admin, "givenName": admin, "middleName": null, "namePrefix": null, "nameSuffix": null, "nickname": null},
```

2nd attempt:

```
"email": null, "fullName": {"familyName": null, "givenName": null, "middleName": null, "namePrefix": null, "nameSuffix": null, "nickname": null},
```

How to prevent this from happening and also how to use logout? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Sign in with Apple, you only get the email/name on first login. It's your responsibility to then store that information. Source:

> The identification servers return the user status only when the user first uses Sign in with Apple with your app. Subsequent attempts don’t return any information for this user status, such as after a disconnect and reconnect occurs or from other devices.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple

Also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496

In terms of logging out, you don't *necessarily* do this with Sign in With Apple. If you're storing credentials on the device, you should purge them from wherever they're being stored. Also, if you're using the credentials for another service (like Firebase), you can certainly log out of that service.

You don't say what library you're using for this, but if it's react-native-apple-authentication, you may want to refer to this thread about logout behavior: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/issues/10#issuecomment-611532131

If on an iOS device, the user can revoke Sign In With Apple access via the Settings app.  See also this related SO question: [Logout from Apple-Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043628/logout-from-apple-sign-in)

Comment: I see.. I thought my implementation is wrong. I'm using this library https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication, saw this 

`await appleAuth.performRequest({
    requestedOperation: AppleAuthRequestOperation.LOGOUT
  })`

but I guess there's an issue with logout?

Comment: Yes -- you can refer to that issue link to GitHub I posted

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask one thing. How about if the user clicked hide email when signing in, how to decode the email via jwt_decode? for example this email tj25rgr5f2@privaterelay.appleid.com

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to turn the private relay address back into their real email address?

Comment: Yes just in case the user hide their email address.

Comment: You cannot decode it -- that is a privacy feature provided by Apple so that users can prevent apps and services having their real email address.

Comment: But still the user can receive an email with that email provided by apple?

Comment: Yes -- it's a relay that sends the email along to them at their real email address that remains hidden to you

Comment: I see the problem is that possible to have duplicate of account, it has the same email but it is hidden because of the relay

Comment: You'd have to test to see, but I'm not sure that that's really the case. I'm guessing their identityToken would be the same

Comment: I  have an application that uses apple sign in. And i know  that if the user sign in for the first time in the application we can get the name, and eamil of the user and an auth id. since i dont update the application since last 2 years so there are more then 1 million user who has sign in (more then 1 time) to application that results in creating duplicate accounts, with name and email are null.   now is there any way that i remove all those users form the apple sign .

Comment: You should start a new question

Answer (score 1):

Apple will give the user name and email of the login user for the first time only, so we have to store the user data to the web servers of our data sources to fetch the user data from the auth id. otherwise, we have to delete the log from the apple login settings to fetch user data again.