# Issue with Sign In With Apple - unable to retrieve name and email

Tags: ios, swift

I used sample code from Apple's Juice example application to implement SIWA. But it returns nil for both name and email. To delete any previously saved credentials, I used this code:

```
    static func deleteUserIdentifierFromKeychain() {
        do {
            try KeychainItem(service: "app.bundle.ID", account: "userIdentifier").deleteItem()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to delete userIdentifier from keychain")
        }
    }
```

Then ran this code to request scope with full name and email scopes:

```
let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.presentationContextProvider = self
        controller.performRequests()
```

When I read the return values from ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential, I get nil and nil. I do get a user identifier but no name or email.

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        switch authorization.credential {
        case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:

            let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
            let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName
            let appleEmail = appleIDCredential.email
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {} will return values once and for all.

Comment: You only get name/email the first time you sign in. See more details on my answer here (on a react native question, but the information and links all generically apply to Sign In With Apple): https://stackoverflow.com/a/66131480/560942

Comment: @jnpdx - Thanks. Isn't that guideline for production and live apps only? I am in a test sandbox. How do I reset the SIWA credentials?

Comment: There's no mention in the guidelines of being able to retrieve name/email beyond the first attempt in a sandbox situation that I can see

Comment: I found the way to reset Apple ID credentials for the App. I am going to re-test in the next hour and report back.

Comment: Going to Apple ID settings -> deleting the app from list of apps using Apple ID reset the SIWA process. Thus allowing me to test in a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apple ID settings -> delete the app from list of apps using Apple ID will reset the SIWA in iOS. Thus allowing you to test in a sandbox.