# Access full name SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to access a users name through login with apple, the Authentication is being created on my Firebase Auth, however , the users name is just an empty string (""), how can I access the users name to store in the db?,

I assume its going to be related to the request of .fullname?. I don't want to track anything other than their name for display purposes.

```js
//
//  AuthenticationViewModel.swift
//  TrackMe
//


//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
import CryptoKit
import FirebaseAuth


@MainActor
class AuthenticationViewModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var currentNonce : String? = ""
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: UsersViewModel = UsersViewModel()
 
}

extension AuthenticationViewModel {
 
    func handleSignInWithAppleRequest(_ request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest){
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let nonce = randomNonceString()
        currentNonce = nonce
//        currentNonce = nonce
        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
    }
    
    func handleSignInWithAppleCompletion(_ result: Result<ASAuthorization, Error>){
        if case .failure(let failure) = result {
            errorMessage = failure.localizedDescription
        }
        else if case.success(let success) = result {
            if let appleIDCredential = success.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential{
                guard let nonce = currentNonce else{
                    fatalError("Invalid state: a login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                }
                
                guard let appleIdToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                    print("unable to fetch id token")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIdToken, encoding: .utf8) else{
                    print("unable to stringify")
                    return
                }
                
                let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
                
                Task {
                    do {
                        if let appleIDCredential = success.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
                            print("Credential: \(appleIDCredential)")
                            // ... rest of the code ...
                        }
                        
                        let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
//                        viewModel.createNewUser(userName: String(, userId: result.user.uid)
                        if let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName {
                            print("Given Name: \(fullName.givenName ?? "")")
                            print("Family Name: \(fullName.familyName ?? "")")
                                                // ... rest of the code ...
                            } else {
                                print("Full Name not available")
                            }
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this happen the _first_ time you sign in? Normally, you only get that info on the first sign in.

Comment: Well, I deleted the account off of Firebase, is there anyway I could get the data to reset so that I can access it?

Comment: It doesn't have to do with Firebase -- it has to do with the Sign in with Apple see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131443/sign-in-with-apple-in-react-native-returning-null and the posts that it links to

Comment: The name is only provided the very first time the user uses Sign In With Apple with your app. If you don't capture it then you can't get it anymore. You an try to revoke the Sign in with Apple (via settings or API call) token but you usually don't get it back just the `user`

Comment: Unfortunate, but I tried with another account after @jnpdx informed me, and it added the name, at least I can just edit my test users directly. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: If you found the answer I linked to informative, please consider upvoting it

Comment: Note, you should not be using `@ObservedObject private var viewModel...` inside a `class`. `@ObservedObject`  is **only** meaningful in `Views`.