# Apple REST API Revoke Auth

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, apple-sign-in, revoke-token

https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke This api for revoking auth from the apple account and getting 200 OK response but still not able unlink apps from apple so do we need to call token api for an access token? If yes here is the screenshot.

API for token generating AuthToken API getting invalid_request so how can we unlink apps from the apple setting account?

As per my understanding.

For https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token
Is `client_id`  the bundle ID right?
Is `client_secret` the identityToken provided by Apple during the Sign In process?..
Is `grant_type`authorization_code or refresh_token

Below Both Not Understood How to Get and also with [auth/token](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) it return ***token*** which we able to pass in [auth/revoke](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) API ?
`code`
`refresh_token`

I'd really appreciate it if someone can explain what should I do with the info provided during Sign in with Apple flow (UserId, IdentityToken, and AuthorizationCode) in order to properly implement the Revoke Tokens API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community already mention in second line ==> getting 200 OK response but still not able unlink apps from apple

Comment: @YuraBabiy No I am find soltion yet.

Comment: I was able to make it work. This answer is useful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73234875/6157156