# Implementing SignInWithApple in a native iOS app

Tags: authentication, swiftui, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple, social-authentication

I am trying to implement `SignInWithApple` in a SwiftUI iOS app which sends/receives requests to/from an external API, which in turn, interacts with a MySQL database.  I have read through all the documentation provided by Apple and as many articles as I can find on the matter, however I am still unsure what to do.

My question is if I am only implementing this functionality in a native iOS app, once I have received the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential`, do I need to keep track of the `authorizationCode` and `identityToken`, or is it enough to just store the `user` (unique identifier) value in my database.  I already issue my own JWT access/refresh tokens as I also allow users to create an account directly with me (via email and password), so I am unsure what to do with those provided by apple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Both of those are time limited and you can get current ones if you need them. All you need is the `user`, the most notable use is to revoke a token. Apple will not approve your app if that part isn't implemented,

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for your response.  When you say revoke a token, would that require me to implement this functionality in my backend server as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73234875/22042015)?

Comment: Yes, Sign in with Apple won't be reliable without a server, not just for revoking from your app but for listening if the user revokes your app from settings, or if the user deletes their Apple ID, etc. There is a ton of documentation on Sign in with Apple on the developer site.

Comment: Yes I've been reading through it, I am just slightly confused as what is required for iOS native `SignInWithApple` since they also provide documentation for web apps as well.  So since I am already issuing my own JWT access/refresh tokens for a user, do I ignore those issued by apple?  I will store the `user` they provided in the database, but is that all that is needed?

Comment: Only you can decide if you need it or not. What I am saying is that only saving the `user` is ok because you can get everything else via your server. iOS `SignInWithApple` does not negate that you need server to server notifications and the ability to revoke tokens, the platform is irrelevant for that part, these things are needed for all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are implementing is similar to when an app uses an authorization server (AS) to manage Sign in with Apple:

- App runs a code flow to the AS
- AS runs a second code flow to Apple
- User signs in with Apple credentials
- AS receives Apple tokens
- AS creates an account if required, containing its own unique user identifier
- AS creates a linked account if required, containing the subject claim from the Apple ID token
- AS issues its own tokens to the app
- If required, the storage means the same user can also use other login methods

In your case you should only need to permanently store the Apple subject claim from the ID token. This could be stored as either a main account ID or a linked account.

If you find later that you need to hold onto an Apple token, eg for revocation purposes, you can use an embedded token approach. This would involve storing an Apple token as a custom claim within your own JWT.