# Sign out after apple sign in

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, apple-sign-in

I just integrated new apple sign in into my app. The first time when I tried sign up I received fullName, email and other credentials in `didCompleteWithAuthorization` method, but on every next attempt fullName, email and other user data is nil. I think that's because the `jwt` token is already generated. I tried to research hot to log out but couldn't find any solution. If someone had the same issue please help me. For testing, I need getting credentials multiple times. So I need to logout somehow.

That's how I request:

```
    let provider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = provider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self
    controller.performRequests()
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried.

Comment: web login appleid, u can deauthorized Apps (sign-out-with-apple :-) there.

Comment: device de-authorize https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426

Comment: Here is a quick solution for subsequent signIn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168825/7551807

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This behaves correctly**

User info is only sent in the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` upon initial user sign-up. Subsequent logins to your app using **Sign In with Apple** with the same account do not share any useful info and will only return a user `identifier` in the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential`. It is recommended that you securely cache the initial `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` containing the user info until you can validate that an account has successfully been created on your server. So next time when a user signs in you have to fetch email and other details from your server using the `identifier` as apple always returns the same `identifier` even when you delete the application and install it back.

Comment: So can't I try initial sign up with same apple Id?

Comment: Apple will return email and user name only first time than after it will return the only identifier so you have to fetch those details from your server. So basically you need to pass identifier to your server in order to fetch user name and email.

Comment: Use `JWT` library to decode token string, the `email` info can be obtained from the token.

Answer (score 3):

For testing purposes you can go to Settings -> Profile (where u can see your Picture) -> Password and Security -> Apps using Apple ID -> Select your app -> Stop using apple ID

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works as designed. But for the specific question you have asked for testing, you can go to user's apple account on apple.com >> Manage Apple ID >> Security >> Sign in with Apple (Manage App and Websites), you should be able stop using the website or app. once you do that, on your next attempt, you will get all requested again.

You can do the same on your iPhone/iPad, under your account >> Password and Security >> Apps Using Apple ID.