# I am getting Email and FullName as nil values when I am trying to SignIn with Apple

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

I have implemented Apple SignIn in one of my application. But when user selects hide my email, then i am getting Email and FullName as nil values. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Add some code show us what you have done.

Answer (score 5):

Did you aware of defining request scopes while you were performing request?

Your code should be some how similar to this:

```
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
```

And when you receive the response, after converting it to `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential`, You can see fullname and email address by printing them out :

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController,
                             didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    switch authorization.credential {
    case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:

        debugPrint(appleIDCredential.email) //prints either 'email' or 'proxied email'
        debugPrint(appleIDCredential.fullName) //prints name 'object'

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**Edit**: 
If problem persists, go to `settings -> profile -> password and security -> apps using your apple id` 
 find your app and revoke its access and try again!

Answer (score 5):

1. If the user select **hide my email** then the value of email will `nil`. No way to get the email.
2. For the first time authentication, you can get the user `fullName`. But in second-time authentication, the value of `fullName` will be `nil`.

For more you can check this: [ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest with name and mail scope returns nil values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593070/asauthorizationappleidrequest-with-name-and-mail-scope-returns-nil-values)

Comment: Thank you @Faysal Ahmed for quick response. If the user select hide my email then I am getting private email id some times and some times getting nil .

Comment: You should get a proxy email if "hide my email" is allowed where emails can be send to real email.