# How to reliably store the email for Sign in with Apple?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

When using "Sign in with Apple" for an iOS app, a design feature seems to be that the user's email is sent in the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` only for the very first sign-up (one can think of that as the "registration"), but not in subsequent events (the "logins"). Instead, the api [returns the user id `sub`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) which serves as the permanent user identifier.

Since this email is useful for apps I need to store this data (sub + email) somewhere so that I will later be able to recover the email from the `sub`. None of the options I've seen work in all circumstances:

1. Store (sub + email) in the KeyChain (see [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593070/asauthorizationappleidrequest-with-name-and-mail-scope-returns-nil-values)). This fails if the app gets deleted and reinstalled, because then keychain data is deleted, but sign in with apple still will not provide the email.
2. Store (sub + email) on my own backend server. This fails if my backend server happens to be down.
3. This wouldn't be so bad if there were an automated way to reset and force users to register instead of logging in, so that I can recover if my backend is down or my keychain data is deleted. That can be done manually by going to iPhone settings -> Password & Security -> Apps Using Apple ID and deleting the app). But this is of course not an acceptable user experience.

This [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496) also discusses these design issues. It's possible that I'm missing something basic, and would be happy for suggestions.

Comment: Your statement in 1 is incorrect; the keychain doesn't get deleted unless the user erases their device.  2. Is the correct approach, but I wouldn't build a special server. Networks and servers can fail so you do need to handle this case.  Presumably if there is a problem with the server or network then you will fail to create the account on your server and you will need to retry next time. You should store the email locally (keychain, UserDefaults or even in a file) so that you can supply it to your server when you retry account creation.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely knowledgeable answer, I'd be very happy to accept as an answer. So it's fundamentally a combination of (1) and (2): The KeyChain is permanent for almost all practical use cases, and good design is simply to also store this relationship on my own server.